# Sorting Colours Using Delta-E

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort a set of colours so that I can display them in the most visually pleasing way. I understand that this is a wide topic and what is deemed as visually pleasing is open to debate, so I have chosen to use the Delta-E algorithm. I am using a [JS library](https://zschuessler.github.io/DeltaE/) called Delta-E.

I can use this algorithm to compare two colours at a time and find the perceived difference between them and it is trivial to run through all colour combinations and store this difference for each combination.

However I am unsure how to proceed beyond this point. Once I have deltas for each pair of colours how do I use these values to order the colours?

What kind of sort do I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually dealing with the same problem right now. One solution I am tinkering with is to set an **anchor color**. What I mean by that is that you'd call your `deltaE` function with the same anchor color and then the color you wish to compare, which will return the difference values from the same color. You can then use that difference value in your [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) call:

```js
const colors = ['#333333', '#f1f1f1', '#00aacc', '#ff6666', '#000000'];
const anchorColor = '#fff'; // White or black might be a decent choice of anchor color

colors.sort((colorA, colorB) => {
  // For each color, determine the color difference FROM the anchor color (not each other)
  const colorADelta = deltaE(anchorColor, colorA);
  const colorBDelta = deltaE(anchorColor, colorB);
  if (colorADelta > colorBDelta) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (colorADelta < colorBDelta) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

However, in my personal testing, I've found that the `deltaE` difference values weren't exactly right for this anchor technique, and I instead used the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Three_dimensions) as the value, [from this library](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#chroma-distance) (which also has a Delta-E function).